Are there any Blazing Fast encryption schemes that allow for the re-randomization of ciphertexts
Are there any encryption schemes that allow you to re-randomization ciphertexts and still be able to decrypt properly which are fast?
They can have a limited messages space (e.g. can only encrypt '0' or '1'). I just need it to be very fast.
It would be great if there was symmetric key scheme but something tells me we will need to use public key.
I know schemes like ElGamal and RSA (I believe) have the ability to re-randomize the ciphertext but are very slow.
Preferably the ciphertext size is also small.

If a symmetric-key encryption scheme has rerandomizability then it is a public-key scheme after all (public key = an encryption of 0 & of 1; encrypt by rerandomizing one of the ciphertexts from the public key). So you are sadly out of luck.

Do you care about ciphertext sizes? In your other question this seemed to be a concern.

Yes the ciphertext size indeed is a concern

@CLox your best bet is probably elliptic curve el gamal if you want small ciohertexts, or RLWE-based things if you want speed. Which is better for your use case is hard to say.
